# SMS messages don't appear for secondary user profile

Tags: sms, multi-user, android-12, profiles, google-messages

This is Android 12 on a Google Pixel 5a. I've got a secondary user profile set up and I've enabled SMS/calls for it.  When logged in to the secondary profile, when I send an SMS to the phone, I get a notification, but clicking it takes me to the Messages app, where it does not appear in the list of messages.  If I search for the message, it does appear in the search results and I can go to that conversation.  But I can't get it to appear in the main list.  It does work fine when I use the main admin profile.

I've tried rebooting and clearing the cache for the Messages app.